# Possible to draw arrow between two items in a list (with SVG?)

Tags: svg

I'd like to draw an arrow between two items in a list. Is this possible using plain old SVG?

This is what I want it to look like:

[image]

I know how to do everything but the external arrow with this HTML:

```
<ol>
  <li>z ← 1</li>
  <li>z ← y × z</li>
  <li>z ← 2 × z</li>
</ol>
```

and CSS:

```
ol {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 0em;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

And honestly I don't even care if I use SVG. If this can be done with Canvas or CSS or HTML or whatever I don't really care. And though I'd prefer no javascript I'll use it if I need it. I'm pulling my hair out with this problem!

Comment: draw a line, put an arrowhead on it with a marker

Comment: But is it possible to draw lines between the items in the list without referring to absolute pixels?

Comment: In SVG everything is absolute, same in canvas. Only HTML has the idea of reflow.

Comment: There is no automatic way to do it in plain SVG. If that is what you are asking.  If you need to do it dynamically, you would need to use JS.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it.

```css
.equation {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5em;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li><span class="equation">z &#10229; 1</span></li>
  <li>
    <span class="equation to">z &#10229; y &#215; z</span>
    <svg height="1em" viewBox="0 0 60 30" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" overflow="visible">
      <polyline points="0.5,15.5,59.5,15.5,59.5,35"/>
      <polyline points="10.5,8.5,0.5,15.5,10.5,22.5"/>
    </svg>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="equation">z &#10229; 2 &#215; z</span>
    <svg height="1em" viewBox="0 0 60 30" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" overflow="visible">
      <polyline points="0.5,15.5,59.5,15.5,59.5,-5"/>
    </svg>
  </li>
</ol>
```

It's not the most flexible approach.  It's not very forgiving of line height changes, for example.  But it hopefully gives you a place to start.